# Hyphenopoly выдает ошибку

Tags: javascript

Вот такую ошибку я получаю:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at Hyphenopoly.js:153:11
    at Hyphenopoly.js:209:7
    at Hyphenopoly.js:933:3
```

Код, который нужен для Hyphenopoly:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  Hyphenopoly.config({
    language: 'ru',
  }).then(() => {
  })
});
```

Все файлы подключил:

```
<script type="module" src="/Hyphenopoly-5.0.0/hyphenopoly.module.js"></script>
<script src="/Hyphenopoly-5.0.0/Hyphenopoly_Loader.js"></script>
<script src="/Hyphenopoly-5.0.0/Hyphenopoly.js"></script>
```